# как реализовать данный блок?

Tags: javascript, html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения] как можно реализовать данную секцию, с наклонённым блоком внутри картинки?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: как сделать чтобы чёрная фигура внутри не вылезала за пределы background?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пример

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 2rem;
}

.section {
  background: #282828 url(https://placeimg.com/1000/1000/arch) no-repeat center top / cover;
  padding: 2rem;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: .5rem;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.section::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #282828;
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 75% 100%, 0% 100%);
}

.section__content {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  max-width: 45%;
}

.section__title {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 2.25rem;
  margin-top: 0;
}

.section__btn {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: red;
  padding: 1rem 2rem;
  color: #fff;
}

@media (max-width: 991px) {
  .section::before {
    width: 60%;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .section__title {
    font-size: 1.75rem;
  }
}
```

```html
<section class="section">
  <div class="section__content">
    <h1 class="section__title">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</h1>
    <a href="#" class="section__btn">Button text text text text</a>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Спасибо Вам большое)